# PHP cURL How to get image width?

Tags: php, image, curl, width

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$h = curl_init();
$headers = array(
"Range: bytes=0-700"
);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //return the image value

$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $h);

$running = null;
do {
   curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running > 0);

$raw = curl_multi_getcontent($h);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($raw);



 $width = imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im);


var_dump($width);
```

I get this ERROR whenever i run the code:

```
> ( ! ) Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized
> format in
> C:\wamp\www\......funcs.php on
> line 399 Call Stack
> # Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0022  294120  {main}( )   ..\...
```

if you `var_dump( $raw )` it says:

```
string '<html>

<head><title>302 Found</title></head>

<body bgcolor="white">

<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>

<hr><center>BSWS/2.1</center>

</body>

</html>

' (length=157)
```

What could be the problem... I have spent over 6 hours now trying to solve the issue... Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are receiving a redirection from the server and cURL is giving you this as the content rather than the image itself.  Try using the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option.

So:

```
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //return the image value
```

becomes:

```
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //return the image value
```

Full list of options for cURL here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

HTH

Comment: Thank You!!... That was it!